# How to set up Scan to folder?

Tags: printing, scanning, ipconfig

So i have a big problem with scan to folder on a Kyocera 3251ci printer.
I usually only have to put in the hostname, the path, Login Name and password. And of course create folder and make it available to write on.

My problem is when i get the Hostname, I always go for the Ipv4-adress, on some laptops i get something like this 192.168.0.115 or something. That zero is i believe the problem cause when i check it would work it gives me back an error. Can somebody please help me with that. What is happening why is it a zero, because every laptop i get with a zero it is not working.

I tried putting in a Ip adress manually but then the internet wont connect with the laptop. I tried ipconfig/ release, ipconfig/ renew and restarted the system.
I dont know what else i can do.

Comment: Not a programming question, so off-topic here. Try [unix.se] or https://superuser.com instead.